# Can I send the user to another .xml with only MAinActvity.java class?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am wondering if you can use a button click to send the user to another .xml layout without a second .java class using the Intent intent = new Intent(this, layout_name.xml);?

or do i have to make another .java class so i can use the Intent.

i used this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) but it didnt seem to workout

**MainActivity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/*
This app is for a local Vape Shop
 it's purpose is to increase customer flow, and provide a menu for Android users

 the array is going to be called = da_menu
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        populateListView();
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // once this button is clicked it wil send the user to the about us activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, aboutus.xml );
    }

    private void populateListView() {
        // Create the list of items

        String[] juiceMenu= {
                "#1 BlueBerry Bombshell",
                "#2 Richie Rich",
                "#3 Chiquita",
                "#4 Afternoon Delight",
                "#5 Poppin Otters",
                "#6 Viva La Sangria",
                "#7 Okole Maluna",
                "#8 Carmen Miranda",
                "#9 Pomalade",
                "#10 Izual",
                "#11 Butter Stotch",
                "#12 Blue Bulls",
                "#13 Grape Ape",
                "#14 Bruce Juice",
                "#15 Doc Holiday",
                "#16 Peachy Keen",
                "#17 Hula",
                "#18 New York",
                "#19 Al Gore",
                "#20 Lux Charms",
                "#21 Sailor Jack",
                "#22 Get Him to the Greek",
                "#23 Key We Lie Chi",
                "#24 Spring Fling",
                "#25 Gumby",
                "#26 Chai-Milk",
                "#27 Mr. Bean",
                "#28 50 Shades of Orange",
                "#29 Blue Waffles",
                "#30 Enigma",
                "#31 Mr. Freeze",
                "#32 Cup of Joe"};
        // Build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,               // context for the activity
                R.layout.da_menu,   // Layout to create
                juiceMenu);         // Items to be displayed

        //configure list view
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**
this is the main page, and the button i want to be clicked is declared with android:id="@+id/buttonAboutUs"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to East Bay Vapes"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonAboutUs" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About Us &amp; Hours of Operation"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAboutUs"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**aboutus.xml**
this is the screen i want the ser to be sent to after the button has been clicked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="About Us"
        android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="We are dedicated to helping people get off tobacco!         We carry everything from beginner setups, to advanced personalized vaporizers, as well as premium juices all made in house! "
        android:layout_below="@+id/AboutUs"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:phoneNumber="false"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:text="eastbay@gmail.com"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="1111 N RD Live, Ca "
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="555-555-5555"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="facebook.com/eastbay"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Instagram: @eastbay"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Monday - Saturday 10:00 am - 8:00 pm\n Sunday 10:00 am - 6:00 pm"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</
```

Answer (score 0):

Intents are used for starting activities, services or delivering broadcasts. Instead you should create two fragments and use a fragment transaction to replace one with the other. You’ll probably have to create a placeholder by using a `FrameLayout` then add the the first fragment to it. Then use a `FragmentTransaction` to replace it.

Edit for elaboration.

You’ll still have your two xml files that describe the layouts you want. But you’ll also have a third with a FrameLayout. Use its layout file for to setContentView. Don’t worry to much about it because you’re going to immediately replace it dynamically.

Create your two Fragments - these are Java classes that will extend fragment and where you will inflate each of your layouts.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout_one = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, container, false); 
    return userIconFragView;
  }
}
```

Then display first fragment using onCreate. Meaning, in your main activity you can then create a reference to the fragments like `FirstFragment ff = new FirstFragment();`

Display it:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction  = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.my_frame_layout_id, ff).commit();
```

In your method that triggers the swap:

```
SecondFragment sf = new SecondFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction  = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.my_frame_layout_id, sf); //1st param might have to be the view group id that contains your FrameLayout, you should double check this, I can’t remember.
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: could you elaborate a little more on that? I dont really follows what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the ViewSwitcher class. There are different ways of doing this but the way I would do it:

1. Create an xml layout that contains only a viewswitcher, give it an id like 'viewSwitcherMain' or whatever you like.
2. Create an xml layout for your first view.
3. Create an xml layout for the second view you want to show the user.
4. In your mainactivity, get a reference to your viewswitcher as you would any other view, inflate your first and second views, and add them to the viewswitcher.

   viewSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) view.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
   View firstLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.firstLayout, null);
   View secondLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.secondLayout, null);
   viewSwitcher.addView(firstLayout);
   viewSwitcher.addView(secondLayout);
5. Go about business as normal until you want to show the user the next view; At this point call: viewSwitcher.showNext();

I hope this helps you out. A good example tutorial (that does it in a slightly different way than I described) can be found here: http://android-er.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/example-of-viewswitcher.html

Android docs for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html

Comment: if i were to use this would i be sacrificing the layout of the aboutus.xml?

Comment: I don't think you have to sacrifice anything here. You simply use a new 'main' layout with only a ViewSwitcher. Then add both activity_main and aboutus to your viewSwitcher. The first one (activity-main) will show as normal, and then you call viewSwitcher.showNext() to show your aboutUs layout. Is that what you want?

Comment: Just to clarify a little further, you don't need to use intents with this approach. The viewswitcher is simply a container that can hold two views and you can switch from one to the other. Also, all of your logic, i.e. adding onClick listeners etc for both views will be in your main activity. Any questions just ask!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this tutorial
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html
I used this to make some Kind of setting Menu where i had some Buttons on the top and switching Different content/ Layout in a fragment.